# TrueCrypt mount processes never quit

Tags: linux, command-line, truecrypt

I'm having an issue with TrueCrypt under Fedora 16. I use TrueCrypt to mount some external device using command line:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/truecrypt  --text --mount -p$pass $src $dest
```

Everything works fine, and when I unmount with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/truecrypt --text -d
```

Everything seems ok, but after a whole day of work I can see in my:

```
ps aux | grep truecrypt
```

that all previous mounting process (those with `--text --mount -p$pass $src $dest`) are still present (two for each mount. If I mount and unmount same device 10 times, I'll have 20 processes like these...

```
root     18025  0.0  0.0 217668  1208 ?        S    Jul14   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
root     18026  0.0  0.0 505048  3640 ?        Ssl  Jul14   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
root     20020  0.0  0.0 217668  1204 ?        S    08:42   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
root     20021  0.0  0.0 431180  3444 ?        Ssl  08:42   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
root     20098  0.0  0.0 217668  1208 ?        S    08:42   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
root     20099  0.0  0.0 431180  3448 ?        Ssl  08:42   0:00 /usr/bin/truecrypt --text --mount /dev/sdc1
```

and the only way to quit them is to `sudo kill -9 PID`.

Does anyone know a solution to let TrueCrypt multiple processes expire at unmount, or to just purge the TrueCrypt processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may caused by `--mount` option, since it's interactive:

```
--mount                     Mount volume interactively
```

You can try without the `--mount` option:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/truecrypt --text -p "$pass" "$src" "$dest"
```

See also [my truecrypt mount script](https://github.com/lenik/uni/blob/master/toolenh/truecrypt-enh/mount.tc.in).